# Soap error parsing wsdl couldn't load from entity Not working in PHP7

Tags: php, soap, php-7, soapfault

My Project Migrated from PHP 5.6 to PHP7 Soap Working fine up to PHP 5.6, when we migrated to PHP7 suddenly we are getting Error

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://apps.test.net/Services/Gateway.asmx?WSDL' : failed to load external entity "https://apps.test.net/Services/Gateway.asmx?WSDL"

My Code Is

```
$wsdl       =   "https://apps.test.net/Services/Gateway.asmx?WSDL";
$apiCode    =   "****-****-****-****-********"; 
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache", "0");
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_ttl", "0");
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
$opts = array(
    'ssl' => array('ciphers'=>'DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:AES256-SHA:KRB5-DES-CBC3-MD5:KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:DES-CBC3-MD5:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA:AES128-SHA:RC2-CBC-MD5:KRB5-RC4-MD5:KRB5-RC4-SHA:RC4-SHA:RC4-MD5:RC4-MD5:KRB5-DES-CBC-MD5:KRB5-DES-CBC-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA:EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA:DES-CBC-SHA:DES-CBC-MD5:EXP-KRB5-RC2-CBC-MD5:EXP-KRB5-DES-CBC-MD5:EXP-KRB5-RC2-CBC-SHA:EXP-KRB5-DES-CBC-SHA:EXP-EDH-RSA-DES-CBC-SHA:EXP-EDH-DSS-DES-CBC-SHA:EXP-DES-CBC-SHA:EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5:EXP-RC2-CBC-MD5:EXP-KRB5-RC4-MD5:EXP-KRB5-RC4-SHA:EXP-RC4-MD5:EXP-RC4-MD5'),'http'=>array(
        'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
        )
);
$params =array ( "encoding"=>"ISO-8859-1",
'stream_context' => stream_context_create($opts),
"trace"=>1,
"exceptions"=>1,
"connection_timeout"=>2000,'cache_wsdl' =>  WSDL_CACHE_NONE);

$client = new SoapClient ( $wsdl, $params );
```

Can any one help Me? 
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you sure that `apps.test.net` is reachable? I've got DNS error while connecting.

Comment: Thanks for replay, its working fine before php7, now it is giving error.

Comment: OK, but are you sure that apps.test.net is reachable?